# How to update a derived table which contains an aggregate function or suggest an alternate way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to update a table. But the query returns error

> Derived table 'colIndex' is not updatable because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause

How can I achieve this? Suggest any alternate way also, if there is not direct way.

Including the query:

```
UPDATE COLINDEX
SET
    COLINDEX.QRESID = ROWINDEX.FRESID
FROM (SELECT QE.COLID,PS.ID SECID,PS.T_ID TEMPLATEID,QE.QUESTIONID,
    MIN(QE.SEQNUM) SEQNUM, Q.QRESID
    FROM SECTION PS
    JOIN SECTIONQUESTIONLINK SX ON PS.ID = SX.SECID
    JOIN QUESTION Q ON SX.QUESTIONID=Q.ID
    JOIN ELEMENT QE ON SX.QUESTIONID=QE.QUESTIONID
    WHERE QE.CONTROLID<>12 
    GROUP BY PS.ID,COLID,PS.T_ID,QE.QUESTIONID ,Q.QRESID)COLINDEX
JOIN (SELECT QE.SEQNUM FSEQNO,QE.ERESID FRESID,PS.ID SECID,PS.T_ID TEMPLATEID,QE.COLID FROM SECTION PS
    JOIN SECTIONQUESTIONLINK SX ON PS.ID = SX.SECID
    JOIN ELEMENT QE ON SX.QUESTIONID=QE.QUESTIONID
    WHERE QE.CONTROLID=12 AND QE.SEQNUM <= PS.COLUMNS + PS.ROWLABEL)ROWINDEX
ON COLINDEX.SECID=ROWINDEX.SECID AND COLINDEX.COLID=ROWINDEX.COLID
AND COLINDEX.TEMPLATEID=5000
```

From part of this query correctly pulls the rows I want update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `COLINDEX` is a derived table - that is, it doesn't really exist - how can you update it?

It looks like what you really want is to update `QUESTION`, which is the table that contains `QRESID`.

You need to restructure your update statement.  It should look something like the following query.  Understand that I didn't (because I can't, not having your tables) test this in any way, and it could be dramatically simplified:

```
UPDATE QUESTION
SET QUESTION.QRESID = Source.FRESID
FROM QUESTION 
   JOIN ( SELECT QRESID, FRESID FROM
     (SELECT QE.COLID,PS.ID SECID,PS.T_ID TEMPLATEID,QE.QUESTIONID,
     MIN(QE.SEQNUM) SEQNUM, Q.QRESID
     FROM SECTION PS
    JOIN SECTIONQUESTIONLINK SX ON PS.ID = SX.SECID
    JOIN QUESTION Q ON SX.QUESTIONID=Q.ID
    JOIN ELEMENT QE ON SX.QUESTIONID=QE.QUESTIONID
    WHERE QE.CONTROLID<>12 
    GROUP BY PS.ID,COLID,PS.T_ID,QE.QUESTIONID ,Q.QRESID)COLINDEX
      JOIN (SELECT QE.SEQNUM FSEQNO,QE.ERESID FRESID,PS.ID SECID,PS.T_ID TEMPLATEID,QE.COLID     FROM SECTION PS
    JOIN SECTIONQUESTIONLINK SX ON PS.ID = SX.SECID
    JOIN ELEMENT QE ON SX.QUESTIONID=QE.QUESTIONID
    WHERE QE.CONTROLID=12 AND QE.SEQNUM <= PS.COLUMNS + PS.ROWLABEL)ROWINDEX
ON COLINDEX.SECID=ROWINDEX.SECID AND COLINDEX.COLID=ROWINDEX.COLID
AND COLINDEX.TEMPLATEID=5000) Source
ON Source.QRESID = QUESTION.QRESID
```

Comment: Possible need replace ROWINDEX.FRESID on Source.FRESID;)